# Fix header in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am developing a small page that is necessary to fix the header of a table, when the user scrolls, the header is still there. I wrote a small piece of code, a sample of my page, in jsfiddle and it isn't working and I don't know why. What am I doing wrong?

You can see what I have done so far [here](http://jsfiddle.net/lfvo/2AKMh/13/).

Follow this [example](http://css-tricks.com/13465-persistent-headers/)

Comment: See http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html for a pure CSS solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it took some time to understand what you need. The thing you want to do is called "floating table header". I have tried all possible jQuery scripts that do that. I have had issues with all of them, but one. If you are simply looking for this feature and there is no sentimental value of your fiddle-code. Then use [Floating header plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/floatHeader). It is the most advance floating header plugin. Check [the demo](http://static.slackers.se/pages/javascript/jquery-floatheader/).

Live demo based on your fiddle, by adding [Floating header plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/floatHeader):
**http://jsfiddle.net/2AKMh/16/**

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your stylesheet:

```
.PersistentHeader{
      position:fixed;
 }
```

Comment: can't be, if i add that, the width of the cell is wrong. i follow this example http://css-tricks.com/13465-persistent-headers/

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this (ignore the sizing and paddings, that was just for my sake to get it to work before i pass it to you):

CSS:

```
td 
    {
        padding:10px;
        }
        th 
        {
            position:fixed;
            background:black;
            color:White;
            width:378px;
            padding:10px;
            }
     #tableContainer 
     {
         width:400px;
         height:400px;
         overflow-y:scroll;
         overflow-x:hidden;
         border:solid 1px #ccc;
         }
     table 
     {
         width:400px;           
         }
```

HTML:

```
<div id='tableContainer'>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing='0'>
    <tr>
        <th>Header</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've faced similar issue and I had some or other problem with floating header rows of table. Some of the problem that I faced were browser specific and some were just obvious e.g. floating header doesn't scroll with horizontal scroll.
At: http://rajputyh.blogspot.in/2011/12/floatingfixed-table-header-in-html-page.html , I tried to solve all the common problems. Hope it will help.